# Not working condition for killing snake plus not working property of an object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making snake game through javascript and I have come to 2 problems.

First problem: I set condition for "killing" snake when his X and Y hits the border of canvas and I can not get why it is not working.

Second problem: My method "draw" of "snake" is working fine how it is written but if I put instead of "var i = snake.dlzka"  "var i = snake.snake_body.length" it types an error: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 650;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var dotW = 10;
var dotH = 10;
var direction = "right";  //smer pohybu hadika

var snake = {
    dlzka: 5,
    snake_body: [],
    
    arraySpawn: function(){
        for(var i = snake.dlzka; i >= 0; i--){
            this.snake_body.push({
                x: i*dotW,
                y: 0
            });
        }
    },
    
    
    draw: function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(var i = snake.dlzka; i>0; i--){
            //alert(snake.snake_body.length);
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fillRect(snake.snake_body[i].x, snake.snake_body[i].y, dotW, dotH);
        }
        snake.move();
    },
    
    
    move: function(){
        var first = snake.snake_body[0];
        var first_x = first.x;
        var first_y = first.y;
        
        
        
        switch(direction){
            case "right":
                first_x += 10;
                break;
                
            case "left":
                first_x -= 10;
                break;
                
            case "up":
                first_y -= 10;
                break;
                
            case "down":
                first_y += 10;
                break;
        }
        
        this.snake_body.pop();
        this.snake_body.unshift({
            x: first_x,
            y: first_y
        });
        
        if((first_x == canvas.width || 0) || (first_y == canvas.height || 0)){
            var restart = confirm("Do you want to play again?");
            if(restart){
                clearInterval(intervalID);
                snake.snake_body = [];
                snake.arraySpawn();
                intervalID = setInterval(function(){snake.draw()}, 33);
            }
        }
    },
    
    
    update_direction: function(e){
        var key = e.keyCode;
        
        if(key == 37 && direction !== "right"){
            direction = "left";
        }else if(key == 38 && direction !== "down"){
            direction = "up";
        }else if(key == 39 && direction !== "left"){
            direction = "right";
        }else if(key == 40 && direction !== "up"){
            direction = "down";
        }
    }
};


snake.arraySpawn();
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){snake.draw()}, 33);
window.onkeydown = snake.update_direction;
```

```css
canvas{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scarface/pdz4k8dj/20/

Answer (score 1):

The first problem arises from the code snippet `(first_x == canvas.width || 0)` Based on [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) rules and left to right evaluation, this evaluates to

```
((first_x == canvas.width) || 0)
```

which is not what you wanted. Try

```
(first_x == canvas.width || first_x == 0)
```

instead but please try and read the rules to make you sure you understand why. Note the test requires the canvas to be an exact multiple of the x (or y) amount the snake is moved by, and it arguably could be better written as

```
(first_x >= canvas.width || first_x <= 0)
```

Don't forget to change the y value test because it has exactly the same problem.

The second issue is due to not taking into account that array indices are zero based. So

```
for(var i = snake.snake_body.length; i>0; i--)
```

iterates from past the end of the array (generating the error) back to the second element. Changing this to

```
for(var i = snake.snake_body.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

worked in the fiddle.